# Using RequireJS with GoogleMaps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, requirejs

I try connect RequireJS and google maps. I have this code

```
    require(['gmapapi'], function(google){
    var map;

      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
        mapTypeId: google.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      map = new google.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
          {});

});
```

In require config `gmapapi: '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false',`

But I get error `Cannot read property 'LatLng' of undefined` How can I access this object?

Comment: And where I execute command: console.log(google), I get undefined

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using async plugin . Added in path

```
async:'//raw.github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins/master/src/async',
```

And in JavaScript file:

```
require(['async!//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true'], function(){
var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');

      var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        navigationControl: true,
        navigationControlOptions: {
          style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
        }
});
```